# Determine if a function is a metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have been asked the following question in one of my tests. I'm not sure of how to do it.

> Consider the plane $X = \Bbb R^2$. For each of the following two proposed
>   distance functions, determine if they make $X$ a metric space.
>
> - $d({\bf x},{\bf y}) = 3$ if *$x_1$ is not equal to $y_1$* or *$x_2$ is not equal to $y_2$* (or both), and *$d({\bf x},{\bf y}) = 0$* otherwise.
> - $d({\bf x},{\bf y}) = 3$ if *$x_1$ is not equal to $y_1$* and *$x_2$ is not equal to $y_2$* (or both), and *$d({\bf x},{\bf y}) = 0$* otherwise.
> - $d({\bf x},{\bf y}) = ( |x_1 - y_1| + |x_2 - y_2|)^{1/2}$

Please guide me on how to solve this.

Comment: Since I have never seen a function that is a metric space, I would say this is never possible. Concerning your question: Check the axioms of a metric. If you can't show one of the properties, you might find an easy counter example.

Comment: The second case for $d(x,y)$ is stated clumsily as "or both" is redundant once the "or" of the first case has been changed to the "and" in the second case.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- Are you familiar with the discrete metric?
- What is the distance of the points $x=(0,0)$ and $y=(0,1)$?
- The only thing to check is the triangle inequality. Note that $\delta(x,y)=|x_1-y_1|+|x_2-y_2|$ defines a metric. Now observe that the function $\phi(x)=\sqrt x$ is increasing and satisfies $\phi(x+y)\leq\phi(x)+\phi(y)$ for all $x,y\geq0$. Can you now prove the triangle inequality? (The root of a metric is always a metric; this construction of new metrics is known as snowflaking.)

Comment: Your answer to the first two seems fine, but I don't understand your point with the third; $\sqrt{2} \leq \sqrt 1 + \sqrt 2$

Comment: I did not understand. Can you please elaborate on your answers ?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, I corrected my mistake in the third point.

Comment: @mike99999, is there some particular thing that you find difficult? For the first two points, I suggest answering the questions: find out what the discrete metric is and calculate the distance. Note that the bullet points correspond to those in your question.